# Mutlicast server and clients ack by sending objects

Tags: java, datagram

I'm implementing a multicast server which sends out its IP to the multicast group and the clients in the group, upon receiving the server's IP, send an object to it.
And this is done at a regular interval.

Thus, the first connection is one to many and the second is one to one.
I have implemented individual parts i.e. multicast, send objects via sockets correctly but I'm facing an error when I run it as a whole.

Here's the code for:
MulticastServer:

```
public class MulticastServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
new MulticastServerThread().start();
}
}
```

MulticastServerThread:

```
public class MulticastServerThread extends QuoteServerThread {
public void run() {
while (true) {
  try {
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];

    // construct quote
    String dString = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
    buf = dString.getBytes();
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1");
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,
                                               group, 4446);

    // server join group。
    socket.send(packet);

    // sleep for a while
    try {
      sleep((long)(Math.random() * FIVE_SECONDS));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    moreQuotes = false;
  }
}

socket.close();
//Sending the object
 try {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    Object to = (Object)ois.readObject();
    if (to!=null){System.out.println(to.a);}
    System.out.println((String)ois.readObject());
    is.close();
    s.close();
    ss.close();
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}
}
```

QuoteServerThread:

```
public class QuoteServerThread extends Thread {
protected DatagramSocket socket = null;
protected BufferedReader in = null;
protected boolean moreQuotes = true;
private static int TTL = 128;
int port=2002;
//Code which returns the IP of the server
}
}
```

On the client's side:
MulticastClient:

```
public class MulticastClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(4446);
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1");
socket.joinGroup(address);

DatagramPacket packet;

// get a few quotes
boolean Condition=true;
while(Condition) {
  byte[] buf = new byte[256];
  packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
  socket.receive(packet);

  String received = new String(packet.getData());
  System.out.println("IP of controller" + received);

  Socket s=new Socket("localhost",2002);
  ObjectOutputStream os=(ObjectOutputStream) s.getOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os);
  Object to=new Object();
  oos.writeObject(to);
  oos.writeObject(new String("another object from client"));
  oos.close();
  os.close();
  s.close();
}

socket.leaveGroup(address);
socket.close();
}
```

I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) on the client's side which
points to the socket creation at client's side.

Can someone please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the encountered error?

Comment: I've included the error in my edit. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the server isn't opening the server socket for incoming connections until the multicast loop has completed which it - afaict - never does due to a "while(true)".

You should start one thread for multicast and (at least) one for the incoming connections so that they can operate separately.